# Use of preposition “of” after “ask,” “inquire,” and “inquiry”

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I’m mystified about the use of the preposition “of” after the verb “ask” and “inquire” and the noun “inquiry.” Would someone help me, please?

First, do these two sentences mean the same thing?

1. I asked my teacher a question.
2. I asked a question of my teacher.

We can say, “That’s all I ask of you,” but #2 sounds incorrect, doesn’t it?

Secondly, please read these two sentences.

3. The police inquired of his neighbors if they knew where he was.
4. The police made an inquiry of his neighbors if they knew where he was.

I feel that #4 is wrong. Am I correct? Should this “of” be replaced by “to” or “with”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In, *"I asked a question of my teacher", "of my teacher"* is a prepositional, adverbial phrase that acts as a complement. This is correct.

In *"The police made an inquiry of his neighbors if they knew where he was."* is wrong.

In order to be correct, *"if they knew where he was"* would have to be a clause modifying *"made"* or *"inquiry"*: it is not. I cannot think of an adverbial example but the adjectival modifying clause would be

*"The police made <s>an inquiry</s> **inquiries** of his neighbors **about whether** they knew where he was."*

Answer (score 0):

Sentences 1 and 2 have exactly the same meaning. The verb *ask* like many other ditransitive verbs has a variation with a prepositional phrase complement instead of two objects, like *give*, *supply*, etc.

> Mark gave [John] [the bread].
>
> Mark gave [the bread] [**to** John].
>
> Mark supplied [us] [weapons].
>
> Mark supplied [us] [**with** weapons].
>
> Mark asked [John] [a question].
>
> Mark asked [a question] [**of** John].

Sentences number three and four are an example of *if* with the same meaning as *whether*.

Similar constructions are to be found, e.g.

> But as he had long been unhappy with the Viennese reception of serious
> art, he was reluctant to risk a concert, and made an inquiry **of** Berlin
> **whether** a performance of the mass and the symphony might be given
> there. (Biography of Beethoven. Biography from Grove / Kunst der Fuge)

Somewhat more common is the noun *inquiry* taking only an interrogative content clause as complement, e.g.

> In response to an inquiry **whether** she had ever been arrested, Lola
> states that she was arrested five years earlier for fraud in
> unemployment benefits. (Policy Guidance on the Consideration of Arrest Records - EEOC)

Though rare, these do also occur with *if* instead of *whether*, e.g.

> But notwithstanding the presence of two beautiful girls, one the
> fairest blonde, the other the brightest brunette, and both kind and
> affable in their manners to him, the young man was restless and
> anxious, until at length, with fierce blushes and faltering tones, he
> expressed a hope that Mrs. Grey was well, and made an inquiry **if**
> she were in. (Victor's Triumph Sequel to A Beautiful Fiend, Southworth, Emma Dorothy Eliza Nevitte, 1819-1899)

> We want to now make an inquiry **of** you **if** you are standing by and
> reaffirming that written waiver of trial by a jury and submit to be
> tried by the panel of three judges who are seated here? (Supreme Court of Ohio, May 17, 197854 Ohio St. 2d 263 (Ohio 1978))

Overall, these seem rather formal in a present-day context.

The variation with *to* also exists with the noun *inquiry*:

> His contract of employment was entirely informal, and consisted of an
> inquiry **to** him **as to** whether "you want to fish with me," and his
> answer in the affirmative. (Domanich vs Doratich, The Supreme Court of
> Washington, 24 Nov 1931)

The *as to* which introduces the interrogative content clause in this example is also a common variation in these constructions.

In sum, replacing *if* with *whether* would probably make sentence 4 more acceptable, but there are precedents for similar usage as it stands.

Comment: Thank you for your answer in detail. It is very helpful. I understand that _whether_ would be more commonly used than _if_, but do you think that there should be a word or words between _inquiry_ and _whether_, such as in “he made an inquiry _about_ whether a performance might be given” or “he made an inquiry _to find_ whether a performance might be given?”

Comment: Both the usage with and without words between _inquiry_ and _whether_ are found. _About_ and _as to_ seem to be the more common ones, and I've yet to find an example with _to find_ followed by _whether_ when used with _inquiry_, but there are plenty of exmamples of this construction used apart from _inquiry_.